# Padding zeros Around an array in order to force it to have the same length

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having a problem following the steps from a research I was given to recreate and I need help completing it. I created a function that takes the peaks of an  ECG recording (heart signal) and splits them into a single beats. For example this is some of the data  the csv file contains  where MLII is the signal that is used

```
'sample #','MLII'
  0,        955
  1,        955
  2,        955
  3,        955
  4,        955
  5,        955
  6,        955
  7,        955
  8,        958
  9,        960
```

And this is how annotation txt is where Sample# is where the peaks are located

```
 Time         Sample #  
0:00.019        7     
0:00.231       83     
0:01.100      396    
0:01.975      711     
0:02.867     1032    
0:03.800     1368     
0:04.756     1712     
0:05.656     2036
```

I started following the steps the research was taking.

For each ECG recording, a dynamic window size based on heart rate variability is
determined by calculating the mean of RR intervals (time spread between two successive R-peaks)
and dividing it in half. Beats at the start/end of the recording, not having enough samples, are excluded from subsequent processing

```
def pk(signal,annotation):  

signal = signal.flatten()

signal= np.array(signal)

cd = pd.read_fwf(annotation)

peaks = cd.iloc[:, 1].values

peaks = np.array(peaks)
```

#I deleted the 2 of the first and 2 of the last peaks cause they didnt have enough samples

```
peaks = np.delete(cd, [0,-1,1,2])

RR_interval= np.diff(peaks, axis=0)
RR_interval = RR_interval/2
```

Once the window size has been determined, beats are extracted by taking L samples from both
sides of R-peaks. Note that length  is different even for traces of the same arrhythmia.

```
R1_interval = peaks - RR_interval

R2_interval = peaks + RR_interval
```

After here I am having a hard time following the remaining steps.

The set of obtained feature vectors  was converted into a single matrix by forcing all vectors to be of the same length. This is done by finding
the maximum length L max to be: Lmax = max{L1,.......Lm} where m is the total number of beat traces and L1,.....Lm represent their individual lengths, i.e. the number of rows in each vector/trace.  After L max was found, all the feature vectors that were shorter than L max were padded by zeros forcing them to be of length L max.In other words, all beat traces are transformed to the largest subspace

Comment: The current issue with your question is that a potentially simpler problem is made to be overly complex with the added details (which are unnecessary). I am sure you can simplify the problem into a simple array-based issue and ask that instead. That would help you and others solve it super quick! . Everything above the statement `After here I am having a hard time following the remaining steps.` can be replaced by a reproducible input instead!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was thinking about the same thing before i uploaded the question  but i thought providing more info might help resolving my problem. I might try compressing it into something simpler